# combinatorics; possibilities of product

Tags: combinatorics

How many series of length $n$ over the group {+1,-1}  follow: $$a_1a_2a_3...a_n=-1$$
I know that there must be a odd number of -1 terms in the product, I noticed the pattern of $2^{n-1}$ and tried to prove it by using induction but got stuck. Any hint will help.

Comment: Hint:  pick any values for $a_1,\cdots, a_{n-1}$.  How many choices of $a_n$ give the right product?

Comment: Two choices, depending on the product of 1 to n-.1

Comment: @lulu Your hint provides in a nice combinatorial proof of $\sum_{k\text{ odd}}\binom{n}{k}=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: I'm saying, fix the choices of $a_1, \cdots, a_{n-1}$.  So that product is fixed.

Comment: @drhab  true!  $\quad $

Comment: You can also approach the question by thinking about red and blue balls. If you have $n$ balls in general, and you know that there is an odd number of red balls, in how many ways can you order them? (all red and blue balls are indistinguishable from each other)

Comment: @lulu I think I got it. Thank you!